# Matching subsequence of length 2 (at same index) in two strings

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, substring

Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they contain the same length 2 substring. For instance a and b is respectively "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz" yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same place in both strings.
What is wrong with my solution?

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
{
   for(int u=i; u<b.length(); u++)
       {
        String aSub=a.substring(i,i+1);
        String bSub=b.substring(u,u+1);
        if(aSub.equals(bSub))
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the inner loop.

Comment: You have more closing braces than opening.

Comment: `s.substring( i, i+1 )` returns a string of length one.

Comment: to encourage you, I vote you up, but please can you have better wording ? it is kind of unclear to me what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Javadoc is not easy to begin with, but then it becomes the best friend ever!

Comment: @KickButtowski But this is a quite clear problem statement?

Comment: @laune It is not quite clear what the op exactly is looking for to me . I can guess but guessing will not help anybody as far as I experience in my life

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya "same length 2 substring" is most definite.

Comment: How long can be your strings? Also, would the length of `a` and `b` be always same?

Comment: @RohitJain Check the example given by OP: the strings don't have equal length.

Comment: Downvoting this question is really unfair. OP has clearly stated his/her problem statement, with a tried out code snippet. What else do we need now? Has rules on SO changed?

Comment: for instance ("aaxxaaxx", "iaxxai") → 3 ("aabbccdd", "abbbxxd") → 1

Comment: it doest noy matter how long my string is

Comment: I would figure out which string is shorter and use that length in your loop condition. Then you will only need one loop.

Comment: The shorter string determines the upper bound of the (single) loop. The length of the substring reduces the upper bound. Iterating over the permissible index values, extract the substrings (note my previous comment), compare and count equalities.

Comment: @RohitJain "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." ... is `What is wrong with my solution?` a proper problem description? You can argue about the downvotes, but this question is obviously incomplete.

Comment: @Tom: *must include the desired behavior* - Isn't it already there in paragraph before the code? *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* - I guess the code is there. Although I understand what you're talking about. OP should have explained what was the outcome of his code, and what outcome he expected, but ignoring that, this certainly doesn't deserve a downvote. You can expect that there are no perfect question, but 'almost' perfect question.

Comment: @RohitJain I'm not talking about the two paragraph you have quoted. I mean the bold paragraph only ;D. Well, I can understand if someone is annoyed of questions where you just have an assignment text (looks like an assignment), some code and nothing else. You don't know what he is he has omitted (other methods for example), if he has an error or an exception or if the output is just wrong. And you don't know what kind of input he has tried except the one mentioned in the assignment text. This can make it quite unclear what the problem is (which is a possible downvote reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix your solution, you really don't need the inner loop. Since the index should be same for the substrings in both string, only one loop is needed.

Also, you should iterate till 2nd last character of the smaller string, to avoid IndexOutOfBounds. And for `substring`, give `i+2` as second argument instead.

Overall, you would have to change your code to something like this:

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i < small(a, b).length()-1; i++)
{
        String aSub=a.substring(i,i+2);
        String bSub=b.substring(i,i+2);
        if(aSub.equals(bSub))
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

Why I asked about the length of string is, it might become expensive to create substrings of length 2 in loop. For length `n` of smaller string, you would be creating `2 * n` substrings.

I would rather not create substring, and just match character by character, while keeping track of whether previous character matched or not. This will work perfectly fine in your case, as length of substring to match is `2`. Code would be like:

```
String a = "iaxxai";
String b = "aaxxaaxx";

boolean lastCharacterMatch = false;
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length(), b.length()); i++) {
  if (a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(i)) {
    if (lastCharacterMatch) {
      count++;  
    } else {
      lastCharacterMatch = true;
    }
  } else {
    lastCharacterMatch = false;
  }
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: is it proper to use Math.min?

Comment: You could also go over the top and computer all possible common substrings... https://code.google.com/p/all-common-subsequences/

Comment: @NihadAzimli Yeah, you can use `Math.min()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The heart of the problem lies with your usage of the [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method.  The important thing to note is that the beginning index is inclusive, and the end index is exclusive.

As an example, dissecting your usage, `String aSub=a.substring(i,i+1);` in the first iteration of the loop i = 0 so this line is then `String aSub=a.substring(0,1);`  From the javadocs, and my explanation above, this would result in a substring from the first character to the first character or `String aSub="x";`  Changing this to `i+2` and `u+2` will get you the desired behavior but beware of index out of bounds errors with the way your loops are currently written.

Comment: @NihadAzimli Just have to think about what the implication is at the end of your loop if i=6 and i+2=8.  How many characters are actually in your string?

Comment: Just changing the substring indices won't give correct result. It will match substrings in two different indices.

Comment: @RohitJain What are you talking about?  You made me doubt myself and I tested it and it works as the OP desired.  I get a value of 3 for count.

Comment: @RohitJain is says true because i tested it for another codes it is not working

Comment: @Foosh Try the code with `xxcaazz` and `xxbaazazaz` strings. You would get `5` as answer I guess.

Comment: ("iaxxai", "aaxxaaxx") → 3 test for it

Comment: @RohitJain heh I should have looked at my test code a little more closely.  I had subconsciously fixed those issues without really comparing against the OP code http://pastebin.com/prVuwwrB

Answer (score 0):

```
 String a = "xxcaazz";
        String b = "xxbaaz";
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < (a.length() > b.length() ? b : a).length() - 1; i++) {
            String aSub = a.substring(i, i + 2);
            String bSub = b.substring(i, i + 2);
            if (aSub.equals(bSub)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```